Buckling length of column frame
The frame is subjected to compression load $P$ at $C$. Find the buckling length of column $CB$.
I started with at location at $B$, with equation of $$v = A \sin(wx) + B \cos(wx)  +M_B/P – Vx/P$$
where $$V = \frac{M_{CD}- M_A}{L}$$
$$M_{CD}= \frac{2EI}{0.5L} (2 Θ_C+ Θ_B)$$
where $$Θ_D= -0.5 Θ_C$$
$$M_{CD} = 6EI \frac{Θ_C}{L}$$
$$M_{BA} = 2\frac{1.5EI}{L} (2 Θ_B + Θ_A)$$
$$M_{BA}= 6EI \frac{Θ_B}{L}$$
At $B$:
$$M_{BA} + M_{BC} = 0$$
$$M_{BC} = \frac{2EI}{L} (2 Θ_B + Θ_C)$$
$$M_B= \frac{10EI}{L} (Θ_B) +  \frac{2EI}{L} (Θ_C) = 0$$
$$Θ_C = -5 Θ_B$$
BC1: $v(0)=0$, $0 = B-M_B/P$, $B = M_B/P$
BC2: $v’(0) = Θ_B$, $Θ_B = wA + V/P$, $A = Θ_B/w + V/Pw$
BC3: $v’(L) = Θ_C$, $-5 Θ_B = w (Θ_B/w + V/Pw) \cos(wL)  -  w (M_B/P) \sin(wL) + V/P$
I am stucked here, can someone enlighten me to proceed further to get the solution?


you wrote sinwx ... shouldn't that be sin(wx)?

@jsotola, yes it's sin(wx) throughout here

then fix it please

I have edited your equations using TeX, check if it works for you.
